# React-native: iOS wont install - libtool error

Tags: ios, react-native

I test my app using `react-native run-ios` in the simulator, however today I just get a random error and have no clue on how to approach it since I com from web dev and have no clue on how to setup projects in xCode (well I have some idea but I don't want to further break the project)

This is the error I am getting:

```
libtool /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/node_modules/tipsi-stripe/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk -L/Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/TPSStripe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TPSStripe.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TPSStripe.LinkFileList -lRCTPushNotification -weak_framework Stripe -framework PassKit -o /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lRCTPushNotification
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lRCTPushNotification is not an object file (not allowed in a library)



** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:

    Analyze /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
    Analyze /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    Libtool /Users/waltermonecke/Code_Projects/reactNative/lisdo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTPSStripe.a normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

I guess this is the relevant part `can't locate file for: -lRCTPushNotification`, but I dont know how to properly remove the reference to that package.

Any help is welcome!